# Memory not freeing after Obj.Close()

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having an issue with regards on memory management with our system.

Basically here is my design:

1. Load the List of the Records. 
   frmBrowse Memory used 
   90MB
2. After clicking record, it will pop another form which is the detailed form of the record      selected 
   frmAP
   Memory used 110MB

   ```
   private void ViewRecord()
   {
       try
       {
           if(oAP!=null)
           oAP = new frmAP();
           oAP.LoadRecordDetails();
           oAP.Show();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           clsClass.oGenMethods.ErrorMessage(ex.Message, "frmBrowse", "EditSearchFields");
       }
   }
   ```
3. When the user CLOSE, i actually Hide it (frmAP  )to prevent re-query datas such as lookup tables and others - frmAP - Memory used 110MB

On the frmAP_Close()

```
this.Hide();
```

-Memory  at 110MB

1. After hiding the form (frmSomeForm ) the memory remains at 110MB
2. When the user close the Form(frmBrowse) where "frmAP" was called/instantiate

   public void tsClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {

   ```
           if (oAP != null)
           {
               oAP .Dispose();
               oAP .Close();
               GC.Collect();
           }
   ```

   }

The Problem is the Memory is Still at ~110MB Whether the List(frmBrowse) Form and the Record form(frmAp) was closed.

Please advice

Thanks in Advance

**UPDATE:**

i Tried to delete .Hide() to isolate the problem, but still the memory keeps growing

Comment: If there is a memory leak (memory consumption grows in time) find it using memory debugging tools. Otherwise, don't worry, GC knows when to release resources.

Comment: If you ever find yourself writing a call to `GC.Collect` (aside from in e.g. memory benchmarks), you're almost certainly doing something wrong.

Comment: Not related to the problem - but currently you only assign `oAP` if `oAP` is not null; if it is null... not

Comment: Ondrej Janacek - Yes i think there is a memory leak since the memory keeps growing. Can you recomend a memory debugging tools? thanks in advance..

Comment: Does anything on this form subscribe to events of things that live **longer** than the form? Event subscriptions with large short-lived objects subscribing to events on long-lived objects (or static events) are the most common cause of keeping things alive unexpectedly.

Comment: @jersoft In that case, check out my answer. Along with other guys, I don't think that you are experiencing a memory leak, but if you think so I will help you.

Comment: @Marc Gravell - I dont have a pooling/timer process inside frmAP.

Comment: @Ondrej Janacek - Thank yiou for you sugestion. But still i close the oAP, still the memory keeps growing.

Comment: When you're running GC your oAP still lives and it is not a candidate to be collected

Comment: @jersoft the point I was trying to make is that if `oAP` is null, you *don't* assign it, they you run `oAP.LoadRecordDetails()`, which will fail with a NRE. Completely unrelated to this issue, though. Did you check for any event subscriptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `Close` does not release the memory associated with an object. That's the job of the garbage collector. `Close` or `Dispose` simply tells the object to release any *unmanaged* memory or resources it is using. The object, and everything it's referencing, still stays in memory.

To ensure `oAP` is collected, set it to null:

```
oAP.Close();
oAP = null;
```

However, this is likely the **wrong thing to do**. The whole point of a garbage collector is to collect memory from unreferenced objects when it's needed. So let it do its job, don't force it to run, you don't need to set `oAP` to null, and `oAP` and everything it references will be collected when the GC needs to.